# Como mostrar registros con cantidad de registros asociados y que muestre los que tienen asociados y los que no tienen

Tags: mysql, sql

Estimados estoy haciendo una consulta sql de varias tablas para ver un listado de vuelos y necesito ver en el listado de vuelos la cantidad de reservas por tramo realizadas. tengo una consulta hecha pero me muestra sólo los vuelos con reservas y lo que yo quiero ver son los vuelos con o sin reservas y en la columna numreservas necesito ver la cantidad de reservas que tiene por vuelo.

```
SELECT V.*,COUNT(TV.COD_SEQ_TVAS) AS NUMRESERVAS
FROM VLOS V,TRMS T, RVAS R, TVAS TV
WHERE V.SEQ_VLOS=T.VLOS_SEQ_VLOS
AND R.COD_SEQ_RVAS=TV.RVAS_COD_SEQ_RVAS
AND V.SEQ_VLOS=TV.VLOS_SEQ_VLOS
AND T.FECH_DESP_TRMS BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-08-07'
GROUP BY V.SEQ_VLOS,V.LNAR_COD_LNAR,V.NUMERO_VLOS,V.FECH_VLOS,TV.COD_SEQ_TVAS;
```

las tablas son :
VLOS:VUELOS,
TRMS:TRAMOS, 
RVAS:RESERVAS 
Y TVAS:TRAMOS DE RESERVAS

La relación de cada tabla esta dada:
vlos 1.* trms
rvas 1.* tvas
vlos 1.* tvas

la consulta sólo trae los vuelos con reservas pero indica cantidades de reservas erroneas y debería traer los vuelos y cada vuelo con su cantidad de reservas y los que no tienen deben mostrar cero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado hacer la consulta con left join pero no me funciona me indica una columna que no existe, pero si existe

```
SELECT DISTINCT(V.SEQ_VLOS),V.*,COUNT(TV.RVAS_COD_SEQ_RVAS)AS CANTIDAD_RESERVAS

FROM VLOS V,TRMS T,RVAS R

LEFT JOIN TVAS TV ON V.SEQ_VLOS=TV.VLOS_SEQ_VLOS

WHERE V.SEQ_VLOS=T.VLOS_SEQ_VLOS

AND R.COD_SEQ_RVAS=TV.RVAS_COD_SEQ_RVAS

AND T.FECH_DESP_TRMS BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-08-23'

GROUP BY V.SEQ_VLOS;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya realice la consulta utilizando left join e inner join y funciona perfecto.

```
select v.*,count(tv.cod_seq_tvas)as cantidadFolios from vlos v
left join tvas tv on v.seq_vlos=tv.vlos_seq_vlos
inner join trms t on v.seq_vlos=t.vlos_seq_vlos
where t.fech_desp_trms between '2019-01-01' and '2019-08-25'
group by v.seq_vlos;
```

Comment: Estoy tratando de enteder la complejidad de tu query. Si lo que queres son vuelos y reservas, te alcanza con la tabla tvas no?

Comment: Lo que necesitas es un `LEFT JOIN`, pero no entiendo porque seleccionas tantas tablas.  No seria suficiente solo con `VLOS` y `TVAS`?

Comment: Hay varias relaciones ya que si se fijan en la consulta en la penultima linea hay un rango de fechas que consulta por fecha de salida y fecha de llegada
esos campos son de la tabla TRMS y por eso es que relaciono vlos con trms ,
ahora para saber las reservas consulto los tramos de la reserva en la tabla tvas usando la reselacion rvas * tvas quizas esta linea esté demas
pero las demas hay que considerarlas. Y con respecto al left join , también pense usarlo pero tendria que modificar toda la consulta me imagino? como quedaría la consulta usando left join o left outer join?

Comment: Hola buenas tardes he intentado hacer un lef join en mi consulta y no he logrado hacerla , como se podría hacer teniendo varias tablas? dejare el código. Por favor su ayuda.

Comment: Tambien prove solo con 2 tablas , vlos y tvas pero ocurre lo mismo, mi indica que no reconoce el campo v.seq_vlos